# White bar on top of page when scrolling

Tags: html, css, macos, scroll

When I scroll up on my webpage I get this white bar on top where the page stops, you can see this in some browsers especially on mac. look at the pictures too see how it looks.
(THIS DOSENT APPEAR IF I DONT SCROLL OVER THE TOP)
But how can I change this to my background picture?

[When I scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lyqc.jpg)

```
#menuBar { 
    background: url("main_background.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:10px 20px; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:2000; 
    width:100%;
}

body {
    background: url("main_background.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Impact", charcoal,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #323232;
}
```

Comment: set the body padding and margin to 0 like body{ padding:0;margin:0; }

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: Check out this: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Araz, dosent work.

Comment: @PinaGamer i have no idea how that works, could find anything that would help my issue

Comment: @ZeevKatz added it as a answer below

Comment: @user7063400 That link provides you a CSS file that deletes the **predifined rules** of your tags and set them to 0 or initial values.

Answer (score 0):

this is how the menu part looks in html

```
 <body>
<!-- menu -->

<div class="menuflex" id="menuBar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sites</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="test/test.html">Test </a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="slider/norsk natur.html">First Slider</a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="TRIPOLOSKI/tri.html">TRIPOLOSKI</a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="#"> Next Project </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>    
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Contact Håvard</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">His company</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Social media</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/havardsnowboard">Facebook</a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/TwintipzZ">Twitter</a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="https://youtu.be/84K2ple-pF0">Youtube</a></li>
          <li> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/twintipzz/">Twitch</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of menu -->
```